# How to iterate item inside an array of objects from req.body?

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, express, request

I have this variable that I needed to fill up using request body

```
        var orderItem = {
            userPurchased: body.userPurchased,
            products:[{
                product: body.products.product,
                size: body.products.size,
                quantity: body.products.quantity,
                subTotal: body.products.subTotal
            }],
            totalQuantity: body.totalQuantity,
            totalPrice: body.totalPrice,
            otherShipAd: body.otherShipAd,
            modeOfPayment: body.modeOfPayment
        };
```

Here is my request body looks like.

[image]

The problem here is that the request body is an array of objects and if I access it in the way I shown on top, it would be undefined. If I put the number of the array like body.products.product[0], all the records will be the same.

Can anyone tell me how to iterate all the products and put it inside the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood what your dilemma is but from the fact that your destination object appears to have the *exact same schema* as your source, why don't you just assign that value to your var?

```
var orderItem = request.body;
```

Let's say you still had some reason to need to create that copy of the array from request.body? This would still be just a one-liner to assign the request.body array to your target variable:

```
var orderItem = {
        userPurchased: body.userPurchased,
        products: body.products,
        totalQuantity: body.totalQuantity,
        totalPrice: body.totalPrice,
        otherShipAd: body.otherShipAd,
        modeOfPayment: body.modeOfPayment
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for that one liner. Maybe I'm just overthinking. Agggghhh. Poor me.

Answer (score 0):

according to your console response

you should use:

```
 var product;
    for(var i=0; i< body.products.length;i++)
    { product = [];
       product[product] =body.products[i].product[0];
    // set all properties
    }
    orderItem.products.push(product);
```